# Extract data from uint8 to double

Tags: c, casting, typeconverter, unsigned-integer

I have a C function receiving a `uint8` pointer with another parameter which is its size (number of bytes).

I want to extract `double` data from this buffer. Here is my code:

```
Write(uint8* data, uint8 size) /* data and size are given by a callback to my function)*/
{
    double d;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        d = ((double*)&data)[i];
        printf(" d = %d\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not receiving what I am sending within an external hardware. I guess that my cast is wrong. I tried other methods but without any good result. I am still not able to get what I send.

Comment: How are you putting the `double` into the data stream? I.E. How are you getting the `uint8` as it maybe in network byte order which could possibly be different than your computers byte ordering.

Comment: Almost everything about this code is hair-raising. What is the exact format of the data you are receiving?

Comment: Like Kerrek SB said, there are many, different problems with this code.  Including the fact that your "printf()" doesn't use "d".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question (it's not entirely clear if there's at most one `double` to extract or there can be many), here's what I would try doing:

```
double Write(uint8* data, uint8 size)
{
    double d;

    if (size < sizeof(d))
        return 0; // failure; you may want something smarter than this

    memcpy(&d, data, sizeof(d));

    return d;
}
```

What this avoids is a potential alignment issue in a cast like `d = *(double*)data`.

This may fail in odd and ugly ways if the data does not represent a valid `double`, specifically if it's reversed (e.g. your hardware is little-endian and the CPU running this code is big-endian or the other way around).

I don't know yet if aliasing issues apply. Need to read the standard again. Never saw them in practice, though.

Comment: I think that this solution is more safe! Thank you!

Comment: *NOTHING* is "safe" unless you know for sure the actual format!  Otherwise, you're just guessing.  And "guessing" is always Bad.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is actually an array of doubles and size is the number of bytes, your code should look something like this:

```
Write(uint8* data, uint8 size) /* data and size are given by a callback to my function)*/
{
  double d;
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<size/sizeof(double); ++i) {
    d = ((double*)data)[i];
    printf(" d = %g\n",d);
  }
}
```

Most likely, size is the number of bytes and not the number of doubles, so you have to divide size by the size of a double to get the actual number of doubles:

If you do this:

```
    d = ((double*)&data)[i];
```

then you are saying that the pointer to the pointer to the data is a double pointer.

Also, your printf statement was like this:

```
printf(" d = %d\n");
```

You were telling it to print an int (%d is an int), and not giving it an actual value to print.  I changed that to %g, which prints a double in best-fit format.

Comment: You're *assuming* that "data" is an array of doubles, and *assuming* that "size" is the #/doubles.  We simply don't know - the OP needs to tell us.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I have a warning about signed/unsigned mismatch.. I receive what I send now. but it seems that i is always equal to 0.

Comment: I have no documentation about size and data.. all what I know is these parameters are given to me from a dll. I am changing an existing code dealing with TCP/IP with ethernet connection.. In my actual configuration, I have two computers connected via Ethernet. Computer 1, changes one or more variables, and computer 2 receives this data. I think that data represents the modified variable in computer 1 and not an array of all computer 1 variables..

Answer (score 1):

```
Write(uint8* data, uint8 size) /* data and size are given by a callback to my function)*/
 {

  double d;
  for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
  d = ((double*)data)[i];
  printf(" d = %d\n", d);
  }

 }
```

is what im guessing you're looking for, the pointer is actually a pointer to an array of doubles so you just cast it to exactly that